# Missing CALLs on identifiers_all using PL/SCOPE

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to use the view all_identifiers from PL/SCOPE to find out calls to procedures and functions but it's not showing all the calls, some are missing.

I have the following code in a package (PKG_1) at line 4216:

```sql
tmpParameterId:=  PKG_2.function1(var1, var2, var3);
```

And when I run the query:

```sql
select * from ALL_IDENTIFIERS where  upper(object_name) = 'PKG_1' and line = '4216';
```

I get the following results(owner|name|type|object_name|object_type|usage|line):

```
SYSADM  var3 FORMAL IN  PKG_1 PACKAGE BODY  REFERENCE   4216    
SYSADM  var2 FORMAL IN  PKG_1 PACKAGE BODY  REFERENCE   4216    
SYSADM  var1 FORMAL IN  PKG_1 PACKAGE BODY  REFERENCE   4216    
SYSADM  TMPPARAMETERID  VARIABLE    PKG_1 PACKAGE BODY  ASSIGNMENT  4216
```

And I do not get the CALL usage to function1.
I have similar code in other parts of the package and it shows those calls.
Really lost here as I cannot tell why some CALLs are being stored in all_identifiers and some are not.

Comment: lower case characters for object names are not a good idea i Oracle, oracle will use upper case anyway if not enclosed in quotes. Try ... upper(object_name) = 'PKG_1'.. in your where statement.

Comment: I'm using upper and uppercase for pkg names, I've gave it a lowercase name when simplifying the code to post here by mistake, edited the post to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Have you recompiled the package called PKG_2 with PLSCOPE_SETTINGS='IDENTIFIERS:ALL' ?

PL/Scope only reports call to objects that it does know about.

If function1 has been created after compilation of PKG_2, PL/scope won't report its usage in PKG_1.

That may be an explanation, otherwise that could also be a bug. If it's the case you'll have to search the Oracle support for keywords describing you problem.